# NodeJS POST method not working with request module

Tags: node.js, post, request

I included require module and trying to post data to a php file.

Code: `request.post('http://localhost/actions.php?setonline',{user});`

There is **no error** and no not working. Do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.post('http://localhost/actions.php?setonline',{user})` is returning a `stream` and you're not handling any of it's events, that's why you don't see any output.

In any case what you probably want is to use a callback, and get the buffered response.

```js
request.post('http://localhost/actions.php?setonline',{user}, (err, response, body) => {
   console.log(err, response, body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I got output and it says "Logged out". There is session check codes in the php page I use post method for. So nodejs can't check it right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by: `node.js can't check it` but if your page requires some sort of cookie, authentication, you have to send it in the request. You can create a sort of `API-key` if you want.

Comment: I update the question. It gives "0:loggedout" error. It's like php codes not working that I write for mysql and database.

Comment: You shouldn't change the whole question, always create a new one. Because that doesn't have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: I understand but you showed how to display error or logs, not how can I fix this problem.